# sel.css selectors :split into two sentences

Tags: python, css-selectors, scrapy

I have a question:
How to split into two sentences?

Here is my original code

```
 sel = Selector(response)
 links = sel.css("div#bargains > article.box h1 > em > a::attr(href)").extract()
```

and because I want to scape another infomation,so I rewrite it like this:

```
 sel = Selector(response)
 sites = sel.css("div#bargains > article.box h1 > em ")
 for site in sites:
    link = sel.css("a::attr(href)").extract()
    title = sel.css("a::text").extract()
```

But this did not work,It will catch another information which I don't want

I know the code below is not correct,I just want to ask how to express the '>' in sel.css in seperate line

```
link = sel.css("> a::attr(href)").extract()
```

Please guide me.thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy *does* support "relative" selector syntax. The problem is with the `sel` variable that you are reusing inside the loop iterations, so you're selecting from the whole document.

Your code should be rewritten to this instead:

```
sel = Selector(response)
links = sel.css("div#bargains > article.box h1 > em > a")
for link_element in links:
    link = link_element.css("::attr(href)").extract()
    title = link_element.css("::text").extract()
```

Comment: Huh, I had noticed that problem when I edited my answer yet somehow missed the fact that that was the *root* of the problem at hand.